# How to update the existing web service with a new docker image on Azure Machine Learning Services?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am currently working on machine learning project with Azure Machine Learning Services. But I found the problem that I can't update a new docker image to the existing web service (I want to same url as running we service).

I have read the documentation but it doesn't really tell me how to update (documentation link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-and-where). 
The documentation said that we have to use update() with image = new-image.

```
from azureml.core.webservice import Webservice

service_name = 'aci-mnist-3

# Retrieve existing service
service = Webservice(name = service_name, workspace = ws)

# Update the image used by the service
service.update(image = new-image)

print(service.state)
```

But the `new-image` isn't described where it comes from.

Does anyone know how to figure out this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation could be a little more clear on this part, I agree. The `new-image` is an image object that you should pass into the `update()` function. If you just created the image you might already have the object in a variable, then just pass it. If not, then you can obtain it from your workspace using

```py
from azureml.core.image.image import Image
new_image = Image(ws, image_name)
```

where `ws` is your workspace object and `image_name` is a string with the name of the image you want to obtain. Then you go on calling `update()` as

```py
from azureml.core.webservice import Webservice

service_name = 'aci-mnist-3'

# Retrieve existing service
service = Webservice(name = service_name, workspace = ws)

# Update the image used by the service
service.update(image = new_image) # Note that dash isn't supported in variable names

print(service.state)
```

You can find more information in the [SDK documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ml/intro?view=azure-ml-py)

EDIT:
Both the `Image` and the `Webservice` classes above are abstract parent classes.

For the `Image` object, you should really use one of these classes, depending on your case:

- `ContainerImage`
- `UnknownImage`

(see [Image package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.image?view=azure-ml-py) in the documentation).

For the `Webservice` object, you should use one of these classes, depending on your case:

- `AciWebservice`
- `AksWebservice`
- `UnknownWebservice`

(see [Webservice package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.webservice?view=azure-ml-py) in the documentation).

Comment: I tried same code its complaining about missing image.id , do I need to pass Image.id aswell ? what other parameters I need to pass and in what format ?